# Should throwing exception be the first thing to do?

Tags: c#, validation, exception

What is the right way (if any...) to validate user input

**This one (first throw the exception):**

```
private void DisposeWorkFlowItem(WorkFlowItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("work flow item must have value");
    }
    //TO DO: add a call to delete the task from worker service.
    _workFlowItems.Remove(item);
    _workFlowItemsStore.Delete(item);
}
```

**Or this one (first do the action):**

```
private void DisposeWorkFlowItem(WorkFlowItem item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        //TO DO: add a call to delete the task from worker service.
        _workFlowItems.Remove(item);
        _workFlowItemsStore.Delete(item);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("work flow item must have value");
    }
}
```

Is there any guidelines?

Comment: If u use the first method, I wouldn't use and else statement there.
As for the question I think its more a preference. I usualy check validation first before doing the "job"

Comment: As far as I can see, both works the same way, `if else` works like two branches, not in sequence...

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion. I prefer the first option, but without the else-clause; this also opens up for throwing other exceptions elsewhere in the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no real guidelines or rules, but the first one is often preferred, because you can remove the `else`, removing one level of indention.

```
private void DisposeWorkFlowItem(WorkFlowItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("work flow item must have value");
    }

    //TO DO: add a call to delete the task from worker service.
    _workFlowItems.Remove(item);
    _workFlowItemsStore.Delete(item);
}
```

Less indention makes for code that is easier to understand, especially in scenarios with multiple such checks.

Oh, and when checking a parameter for `null` you usually throw an `ArgumentNullException` with the parameter name as the first parameter:

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
```

Answer (score 2):

Like commentor stated i would go as follows:

```
private void DisposeWorkFlowItem(WorkFlowItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("work flow item must have value");
    }

        //TO DO: add a call to delete the task from worker service.
        _workFlowItems.Remove(item);
        _workFlowItemsStore.Delete(item);

}
```

and doing validation at first is usually my preference. You need to check the correctness or the state or the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same to me and for as far as I know there are no guidelines to this.

For readability I'd suggest to put the eception first though.

E.g.

```
if (...) throw new Exception();

do your thing
```